# assume a solar eclipse is not predictable, how can I compute the self-information of “there will be a solar eclipse tomorrow morning”?

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

section 3.13 on the [deeplearningbook](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/prob.html) says

A message saying “the sun rose this morning” is so uninformative as to be unnecessary to send, but a message saying “there was a solar eclipse this morning” is very informative.

the self-information of an event $X=x$ is in this form

$I(x) = -\log P(x)$

assume a solar eclipse is not predictable and there are N days when there was a solar eclipse, in the 100 years between 1900 to 2000.

the self-information of “there will be a solar eclipse tomorrow morning” is approximately equal to

$-\log \frac{N}{365*100}$

am I doing this correctly?